What may these eggs belong to?
Today I've found these eggs on the outside of my house.
This is located on the north of Spain.

Do anyone knows what it belongs to?
I'm leaning towards something related to the Reduviidae family?
google image search for Reduviidae

Oddly enough - English being the weird language that it is, the phrase is "leaning towards" for something you are thinking might be the right answer. Leaning against would mean not the right answer.

Just did a snap Google search for "assassin bug eggs" and the images that came up were very reminiscent of yours; here's a link to a good article with an image: https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/michigan-insects-in-the-garden-week-3-assassin-bugs. So yeah, most likely possibility is assassin bug eggs.
